# Okio/Okhttp download file using BufferedSink and decode Base64 without having whole file in memory multiple times

Tags: java, android, okhttp, okio

Got a bit of a problem atm. for my "inapp"-update im downloading the new base64 encoded .apk from my webspace. I have the functionality pretty much down, this is the code without decoding.

```
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                ResponseBody body = response.body();
                BufferedSource source = body.source();
                source.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                Buffer buffer = source.buffer();

                String rString = buffer.clone().readString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                Log.i("Test: ", AppUtils.decodeBase64(rString));

                if(rString.equals("xxx")){
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new KeyNotValid());
                    dispatcher.cancelAll();
                }else{
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new SaveKey(apikey));
                    BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(myFile));
                    sink.writeAll(source);
                    sink.flush();
                    sink.close();
                }
            }
        }
```

The Buffer/Log is not really necessary, just using it to check the response during testing.

How would i go about decoding the bytes before i write them to the sink?
I tried doing it via. ByteString, but i couldn't find a way to write the decoded String back to a BufferedSource.

Most alternatives are pretty slow like reopening the file afterwards, reading the bytes into memory, decode and write them back.

Would really appreciate any help on this

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can already consume the response as an InputStream via ResponseBody.byteStream.  You can decorate this stream with https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.html and use it to read a stream of bytes and write it to the Sink for the file in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer arrives quite late and that Yuri's answer is technically correct, but I think the most idiomatic way to do that is to take advantage of the composition pattern promoted by Okio to create a `Source` that decodes from Base64 (or a `Sink` that encodes to Base64, if you need so).

Here's a little proof of concept (I'm sure it can be improved):

```
public class Base64Source implements Source {

    private Source delegate;
    private Base64.Decoder decoder; // Using Java 8 API, but it can be any library

    public Base64Source(Source delegate) {
        this(delegate, Base64.getDecoder());
    }

    public Base64Source(Source delegate, Base64.Decoder decoder) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.decoder = decoder;
    }

    @Override
    public long read(Buffer sink, long byteCount) throws IOException {
        Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
        long actualRead = this.delegate.read(buffer, byteCount);
        if (actualRead == -1) {
            return -1;
        }

        byte[] encoded = buffer.readByteArray(actualRead);
        byte[] decoded = decoder.decode(encoded);
        sink.write(decoded);

        return decoded.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Timeout timeout() {
        return this.delegate.timeout();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        this.delegate.close();
    }
}
```

And here's how it can be used

```
BufferedSource source = Okio.buffer(new Base64Source(originalSource));
BufferedSink sink = ... // create sink
sink.writeAll(source);

// Don't forget to close the source/sink to flush and free resources
sink.close();
source.close();
```